# Remember selected ListView Items

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android and I have following problem

I have a ListView. The ListView is filled with data from an ArrayList. I added a CheckBox to every row.

After clicking on a "Resume-Button" I want to write the selected items to a SQLliteDB (the db works fine - I tested it with static data).

My question is now: 
How can I get the checked items from the list?

Thx everyone for help!
Best regards
kyp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this ListView method [getCheckedItemPositions()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemPositions%28%29) to get all the checked positions. Make sure that the child view in your ListView actually implements the [Checkable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html) interface otherwise the checkmark information will not be passed along to the ListView.

Comment: thanks! With that I finally managed it and I will post my solution later.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the list, using a for loop and getItemAtPosition(int).
For each row you just check if the item is checked, isChecked() for a checkbox. Without seeing the code that is as specific as I can get. If this is not clear enough then post some code about how/what items are stored in the listView

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this. But I didn't get it worked with my custom layout. :(

Answer (score 0):

But i figured it out myself.
I only wanted to select the row by clicking on the checkBox view.

I modified my custom Array Adapter

Here is my code:

```
public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> implements OnClickListener{

private static HashMap<Integer, Boolean> teamItems = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
int count = 0;

private List<Contact> items;
private int mode;

CheckBox add_to_team;
static int counter = 3;

public ContactAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Contact> objects, int mode) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.mode = mode;
    this.items = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if(v == null) {
        //get a reference to the LayoutInflator
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //and inflate our XML into the View
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.list_contacts_item, null);
    }

    String race = items.get(position).race;
    String nick = items.get(position).nick;
    String name = items.get(position).name;
    final int pos = position;

    if(v!= null) {
        // Do the work for the other views

        // MODE 1 = SELECTION-MODE  
        if(mode == 1) {

            add_to_team.setVisibility(0);

            try {
                if(count!=0) {
                    boolean b = teamItems.get(pos);
                    if(b==false) {
                        add_to_team.setChecked(false);
                    }
                    else {
                        add_to_team.setChecked(true);
                    }
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {

            }

            add_to_team.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                    teamItems.put(pos, arg1);
                    count++;
                }
            });
        } else {
            add_to_team.setVisibility(8);
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

}

I added a HashMap in which I save the selected items. I can call the select state from my activity, by calling the HashMap... And it works great!